# How is this ADC voltage reference buffer not unstable?

Tags: operational-amplifier, analog, adc, stability

See attached images. They show an ADC voltage reference buffer with 22uF of output capacitance, a graph of the OPA350 stability with capacitive load and isolation resistance, and an ADI document about in loop compensation for driving heavy capacitive loads.

It’s a simple question: how come this operational amplifier won’t oscillate with such a high capacitive load beyond its specification? There is no technique for compensation in or outside of the loop, and it is unity gain configuration which is the most likely to become unstable. There is expected significant overshoot with this level of capacitive load. I have also seen this type of buffer on the output of an ADC sampling channel, with an isolation resistance of around 20Ohm, driving capacitances in the range of tens of nanofarads. So it is clear I am missing something that makes this ok, despite the lack of compensation.

EDIT: after a reply by Tim Wescott, I am attaching a fourth image which shows the capacitive load for different series resistances. The amplifier is LT6233.

[image: capacitive load drive OPA350]
[image: Launchpad ADC reference buffer]
[image: ADI in-loop compensation for very large capacitive loads]
[image: LT6233]

Comment: I think , this operational amplifier has a compensation capacitor inside it . It is internally stabilized …

Comment: I do not see any such compensation capacitor in the internal circuit diagram, and even if so, the capacitor on the output of the buffer still seems to violate the specification maximum…

Comment: Yes, they will not show that in the datasheet it’s a two stage op amp with push pull output m so if you do a search in the literature you will see that it common to compensate that kind of structure internally … and yes 22uF is above the spec , but I see a zero on your circuit , may be it help to stay stable , not sure as there is not enough details

Comment: I didn’t even think about the series resistor with the load capacitance. That should give a zero of around 70kHz or so, well below the bandwidth of the amplifier, so maybe it’s that. I think this technique must only work when output capacitance as tens of microfarads, otherwise the series resistor would be quite large to get the same zero frequency.

Answer (score 0):

> how come this operational amplifier won’t oscillate with such a high capacitive load beyond its specification?

Look at the overshoot vs. load capacitance chart that you posted -- the overshoot levels off, and even goes down in the \$\mathrm{A_V}=1\$ case as the capacitance goes up to \$1\mathrm{\mu F}\$.  If you extrapolate that curve, you would expect no more than 70% overshoot (which is horrible, but doesn't mean the circuit is *unstable*).

Note that the resistors R11 and R52 in the schematic should stabilize the circuit somewhat, and may reduce or eliminate the overshoot.  To figure out the exact effect you'd need to use that chart, and the open-loop gain chart, to back out the op-amp's effective open-loop output impedance.  Knowing that output impedance you could determine the overshoot with the resistor either in a SPICE simulation or on paper.

Comment: Thanks Tim, that makes sense - I will take another look at this in SPICE tomorrow. I have updated my question as I cannot send photos in comments. How would you go about deciphering the maximum capacitive drive for other amplifiers if the overshoot does not level off? You can see a sharp decline in overshoot in this amplifier as capacitive load reaches a certain point. Can you determine which would be the best amplifier for driving a load of 22uF from these charts? Can any amplifier drive that type of load if compensated accordingly?

Comment: The questions you ask are specifically about driving a capacitive load with an op-amp.  They are, first of all, a separate question and stackexchange is all about asking **one** closed-ended question and getting answers; second of all, I'd be astonished if it hasn't been answered here already.  So search on "op-amp" and "capaticive load", and if that doesn't work then please feel free to start a separate question.